# Read and process many files in parallel

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, multiprocessing, out-of-memory

Using the following code, I'm trying to read, process and concatenate a bunch of CSV files in parallel.

```
def read_process(file): 
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    process_df(df)
    return df 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = '/path/to/directory/'
    files = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in os.listdir(path)]

    with Pool() as pool:
        dfs = pool.map(read_process, files)
        df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

However, the memory consumption exponentially increases for large datasets. How can I limit the amount of used memory by `Pool`?

Comment: maybe limit number of workers - ie. `Pool(2)` for 2 workers.

Comment: or maybe in `read_process` and save csv in new file - and later create code which read csv in chunks and save in other file.